# Deleting files in a server using shell script

Tags: bash, shell, unix

How do you delete a file in a server after doing a wget of all the files?
I understand the delete command works, when you are have done a ftp into the server, but I am unable to use the command while running a shell script. Below is my script, kindly let me know what is wrong in it.

```
#!/bin/bash

filelist='ls *20120330*'
for file in $filelist
do
ftp -vn <$hostname> <<EOFD
  quote USER <username>
  quote PASS <Pass>
binary
 ls -lrt *20120330*
 delete $filelist
quit
EOFD
done
```

Comment: Have you considered using `rsync`?

Answer (score 5):

You want

```
for file in *20120330*
```

rather than a loop over the literal words `ls` and `*20120330*`. If your real use case is much, much more complex, there could be a reason you want the file list in a variable, but my guess is that you don't, and never will.

(What you were probably thinking was

```
for file in `ls *20120330*`
```

but that is also wrong, for different but related reasons. See also http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html#ls)

Tangentially, you are probably better off creating a script which deletes all the file names, rather than creating a new ftp session for each file you want to remove;

```
#!/bin/bash

dellist=
nl='
' # yeah, nl is a newline in single quotes
for file in *20120330*
do
    dellist="delete $file$nl"
done
ftp -vn <$hostname> <<EOFD
  quote USER <username>
  quote PASS <Pass>
  binary
  ls -lrt \*20120330\*
  $dellist
  quit
EOFD
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `rm` instead of `delete`

Answer (score 0):

If it's an option, I'd recommend using [ncftpget](http://www.ncftp.com/ncftp/) instead of regular ftp, as it has features that make it friendlier to scripting like this.

Answer (score 0):

ftp command

```
prompt
mdel  *20120330*
```

Answer (score -1):

```
#!/bin/bash
username=luser
password=secret
hostname=localhost

filelist=`ls *20120330*`
for f in $filelist; do
ftp -vn ${hostname} <<EOFD
  USER ${username}
  PASS ${password}
  binary
  ls -l ${f}
  delete ${f}
  quit
EOFD
done
```

Comment: See the link in my answer for why you should avoid `ls` in backticks.

Comment: I know the shell can do the globbing. But at least I corrected the single quotes (which) were **wrong** into something usable. (didn't test, don't want to fire up FTP here)

Comment: It will fail if there are files with whitespace in their names, or if the wildcard matches a directory. The fix is easy; don't use `ls` and don't attempt to put the results of a glob in a variable.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. It will also fail when the number of files is larger than ARG_MAX. (the same for the method that uses shell-globbing)

Comment: Actually, the shell (in reasonably modern implementations) will handle globs which expand to more than `ARG_MAX` bytes as long as the command is a shell builtin. The limit is on the `exec` family of calls.