# What does EOFD mean?

Tags: bash, definition, acronym

While browsing SO I sometimes see EOFD for example:

```
ftp -vn <$hostname> <<EOFD
```

Yes I tried Google with no luck, just in case you are wondering.

Comment: dunno about `D`. But EOF = End Of File

Comment: End OF Data, maybe?  The identifier used in a [here document](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document) can be anything you like.

Comment: as @blahdiblah pointed out I was referencing [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10013151/85950)

Comment: `EOF` stands for *end-of-file* the `<<xxx` is a delimiter for a here-document so perhaps `EOFD` stands for end-of-file delimiter or end-of-file data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the context of [the question you reference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10013151/85950), `EOFD` doesn't mean anything special, it's just the start of a bash [here document](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html).

From the [Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html):

> A *here document* is a special-purpose code block. It uses a form of I/O redirection to feed a command list to an interactive program or a command, such as ftp, cat, or the ex text editor.
>
> ```
> COMMAND <<InputComesFromHERE
> ...
> ...
> ...
> InputComesFromHERE
> ```
>
> A *limit string* delineates (frames) the command list. The special symbol `<<` precedes the limit string. This has the effect of redirecting the output of a command block into the `stdin` of the program or command. It is similar to `interactive-program < command-file`, where `command-file` contains
>
> ```
> command #1
> command #2
> ...
> ```
>
> The `here document` equivalent looks like this:
>
> ```
> interactive-program <<LimitString
> command #1
> command #2
> ...
> LimitString
> ```
>
> Choose a `limit string` sufficiently unusual that it will not occur anywhere in the command list and confuse matters.

So in that question, the author was sending commands to `ftp` as if using it interactively.

Answer (score 3):

Try again with these search terms: [*here document*](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=here+document)

Answer (score 3):

The `<<EOFD` construct is a special type a redirection for shell scripts (Bourne, bash and I'm not sure what others) that tell the shell to treat the lines follow as the `stdin` stream until a line that consists of `EOFD` is seen.

The `EOFD` string is arbitrary - any unique token (or at least one that won't be in the `stdin` input stream).

Answer (score 1):

Since these words are arbitrary, why would anyone write `EOFD` rather than the customary `EOF`?

(And, by the way, there is also the tradition of using the `!` character:

```
cat <<!
Hello
world
!
```

)

`EOFD` might be useful if the text you're generating with a here document is itself a shell script which itself contains here documents, and those here documents already use `EOF` for delimiting:

```
cat <<EOFD
#!/bin/sh
# here doc script
cat <<EOF
Hello
World
EOF
EOFD
```

:)

Comment: I have not seen the `!` tradition (that I recall anyway).  `EOF` and `end` (in upper and lower case) are pretty common, and some people use different end markers for each here-document in a script, presumably to make them easier to find.